# What is the difference between NIO and JMS

Tags: java, jms, nio

As I understand Java NIO is an API to help create event-driven applications. Where you use a selector to notify your application of any data received over a SocketChannel.
JMS(Java Messaging Service) is a messaging framework for sending/receiving messages between clients.

Is JMS a abstraction of Java NIO API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NIO just stands for New IO.  It's an enhanced general Java IO package, that has a lot of support for asynchronous IO, but also contains quite a few other enhancements, like support for grepping through filenames.  You would use it when you're trying to do something that's not supported by the classes in java.io.

JMS is a java messaging system.  You can use it when you need to have two applications talk to one another over a queue-like system.  Whether or not it uses NIO under the hoods is an implementation detail, though various JMS providers written in Java probably do.

Comment: JMS is a Java API to *interface* to an external messaging system. It is not a 'Java messaging system'.

Comment: NIO does not stand for New IO, rather it is "Non blocking IO". The name explains it behavior as well, where reading/writing to byte and channels do not block the thread of execution.